# How can i iterate through sessions in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I pushed to various sessions some values through foreach loop. For example:

```
$queries = Model::all();

foreach($queries as $query){  
    $request->session()->push('id',$query->id);  
    $request->session()->push('title',$query->title);  
    $request->session()->push('name',$query->name);
 }
```

So in another controller i need to retrieve these values from session and put them in query array where i also use foreach loop.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: How can i retrieve them from another controlle so i can put those values in another queries values.

Comment: set all `queries` at once

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$request->session()->get('key', 'default');
```

to retrieve it in another controller which will return an array in your case